# Cannot get Woocommerce order by ID

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have created a function that is supposed to update certain meta fields once an order has been placed with Woocommerce.
Although I can confirm that the function is fired, I cannot seem to be able to load the order by the ID. Here is my code so far:

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'wc_update_bib_options');
function wc_update_bib_options($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // Some stuff...
    }
}
```

I can confirm that `$order_id` is passed and is an integer. Also, if I enter an ID of another (previous) order, the code works just fine...
I also tried using

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
```

But I get the same results...

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: do you want to add custom meta field to your order?

Comment: I think that this is not the right hook as it's used when a new order is created  so may be the id is not yet really defined… see this hook is located in `create_order()` WooCommerce core function: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#171 … and the hook is on line 231. You should try another hook to achieve this…